# Controlling DC motor without Arduino motor shield

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, control

I am trying to make a line follower with the help of [this](http://www.buildcircuit.com/easy-steps-for-making-a-line-following-robot-using-infrared-led-photodiode-ardumoto-and-arduino/) tutorial. In the tutorial they have used Arduino motor shield. I want to know, is there any way to control the motors without using Ardumoto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't connect a motor directly to an Arduino. The Arduino cannot supply enough current. You need a motor driver. But any motor driver circuit will do, it need not be that exact one. Be sure to get a motor driver with good documentation, so that you'll know how to write the code (sketch) to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Ardumotor is a very basic breakout of a standard 2 motor h bridge ic. Any [H-bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_bridge) can replace it.